# Get specific response value from the API in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices, rest

I am calling one post call and getting the response like below :
[image]

Now I want to get the value of the access token and do some logic. How to get the value from the response? Can anyone please help.
Service code of the API.

```
public String getToken(User user) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(clientId+clientPass);
        String plainCreds = clientId+":"+clientPass;
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        HttpEntity<String> request=new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        String uri = url+ user.getUser_id()
                + "&password=" + user.getPassword();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class) ;
        JsonNode newNode = mapper.readTree(result.getBody());
        ObjectNode node = ((ObjectNode) newNode).put("Authentication", "Successful");
        
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/authenticationprincipal-getting-the-jwt-claims/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
I used

```
node.get("access_token")
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can write DTO for response:

```
public class ResponseSample {
   @JsonProperty("access_token")
   String accessToken;
   ....
}
```

(or deserialize to Map)
and instead calling `ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(...)` you can call

```
ResponseEntity<ResponseSample> result = restTemplate.exchange(..., ResponseSample.class)
```

Comment: I used node.get("access_token") and it worked. Anyway thanks for your time!